# Multiple URL's for news entry?

Tags: entry, url, routing, format

For news entries I want both URL's www.example.com/news/678 (where 678 stands for the entry id) and www.example.com/news/some-slug to load the same entry.

www.example.com/news/some-slug works fine because 'Entry URL Format' is used for this so the news entry contains a readable slug for SEO.

Is there a way to generate www.example.com/news/678 (with entry id) for the same entry, to display the same news entry? Is it possible to handle this with Dynamic Routing? Or generate multiple URL Formats?

Comment: You probably don't want to do this. Duplicate content will give you a SEO penalization.

Comment: I need the url's with entry id for external usage. No problem to change to www.example.com/**some-other-text**/678 for example and disallow it in robots.txt to prevent a SEO penalty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup a dynamic route that points to the same template that you have set up in the section settings for your "slug URLs". Use a pattern like so: `news/<id>`, which passes the 2rd URL segment as a variable named `id` to the template.

Add this snippet to the top of your template.

```
{% if not entry and id %}
    {% set entry = craft.entries.id(id).first() %}
{% endif %}

{% if not entry %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}
```

If Craft finds a route for your entry slug ([routing case 3](https://craftcms.com/docs/routing)), that code does nothing at all, because the entry model is already set.

When no route was found that matches an entry slug, your dynamic route comes into play ([routing case 4](https://craftcms.com/docs/routing)), which routes the request to the same template.
But now there is no entry variable set and we can go ahead and try to grab it manually using the `id` variable passed in.

**Update:**
as already mentioned in the comments, **don’t forget** to setup canonical meta tags to avoid duplicate content penalties.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="{{ entry.getUrl() }}">
```

Comment: Thanks carlcs! With the pattern 'news/<id>' added in cp --> routes, it gives a 404. When I add `'newsid/(?P<id>\d{3})' => 'news/_entry'` it works fine for 3-digits id's. I'd like to accept all digits, but when removing \d{3} this route gives a 404 again.

Comment: Ahh… that <id> syntax wasn’t meant to be actual code, sorry. I thought there was a draggable ID token available in the UI. I never actually use that interface and setup my routes with the craft/config/routes.php file. Where I would use the following: `'news/(?P<id>\d+)' => 'news/_entry'`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing how this could be done through routes.

Maybe you could do it with a custom plugin that listened to the [getElementRoute](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#getElementRoute) hook, though.

There is a feature request here you might want to thumb-up/comment on that would seem to do what you're looking for: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1189